# Three infected files in wine-staging. How I should proceed?

Tags: wine, network-manager, uninstall, malware

An analysis run with `clamtk` reported three infected files and I wasn't able to remove it from `clamtk` or in terminal.

Its appear in screen as:

```
/opt/wine-staging/lib/wine/fakedlls/clock.exe    
/opt/wine-staging/lib/wine/fakedlls/comctl32.dll    
/opt/wine-staging/lib/wine/fakedlls/user32.dll
```

Should I remove opt folder? Should I uninstall `wine-staging`? Is this even possible?
I don't know how to get these done.

Comment: Always use more than 1 scanner. If both show an alarm time to investigate, if not assume it is a false positive. And if you want to be really sure: yes, nuke the directory and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an advice? Do not trust Linux antivirus software. Besides not being strictly needed, they usually detect (and may even remove) some important files as if they were malware. That's it. If you downloaded wine through the official repositories or directly from the Wine website, you don't need to worry. And those files are a DOS/Windows executable and two shared libraries, they won't affect your system. Do not remove /opt, it's a system directory and you may lose your programs.

Comment: Well... I am not sure about it... But it also happens with mimo.info file ... I don't think that it would be sure to keep wine working...

Comment: That is not specific to "linux antivirus" but to "antivirus". 99% of notices are false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I did an entire scan of `/opt/wine-staging/` using `clamscan` result showed no infected files.

ClamAV

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4144414
Engine version: 0.98.7
Scanned directories: 17
Scanned files: 1693
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 154.44 MB
Data read: 152.23 MB (ratio 1.01:1)
Time: 67.035 sec (1 m 7 s)
```

You may want to purge `wine-staging` just to be clear you followed these [Installation instructions](https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/wiki/Installation#-ubuntulinux-mint)

To completely remove wine-staging run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine-staging

sudo rm -Rf /opt/wine-staging/
```

Then install it again.

```
sudo apt-get install wine-staging
```

Comment: It worked properly, I've just scaned opt folder and it came out clean... thank you very much...

Comment: As you say it worked for you, please do not forget to click the grey **☑
** at the left of this text,
which means [Yes, this answer is valid !](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) :)